# Having trouble mapping highcharter aesthetics to reactive object elements

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, dplyr, reactiveui

I have a large shiny app that allows users to filter through an API and spark table aggregate (dumped to an .Rdata) simultaneously using the same set of initially selectized parameters.  Fitting all this into a reproducible example is going to be tough, but, this is the function that is grouping and summming my metric of interest (try to resist asking me to paste in `partitionFiltered()`):

```
df <- reactive({partitionFiltered() %>%
      dplyr::group_by(updatedTimeHour, direction) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(count_dir = sum(n_flows)) %>%
      dplyr::ungroup() %>%
      dplyr::select(updatedTimeHour, direction, count_dir) %>%
      dplyr::arrange(updatedTimeHour) %>% 
      unique()})
```

(Eventually, `updatedTimeHour` and `direction` will be replaced by `input$periodicity` and `input$dimension`, respectively, but that is beyond the scope of this question.)

The `df()` object looks like:

```
updatedTimeHour direction   count_dir
6               1           525071.00
6               2           3491.00
6               0           498816.00
6               3           5374.00
7               2           2432.00
7               0           303818.00
7               1           340768.00
7               3           4852.00
8               1           1969048.00
```

My highcharter calls do not seem to be grouping and coloring the aesthetics as I would expect:

```
        hc <- highchart() %>% 
              hc_add_series(data = df()$count_dir, 
              type = input$plot_type,
              name = factor(df()$direction)
              showInLegend = TRUE,
              # ??group = df()$direction,
              # ??color = df()$direction,
              # ??x = df()$updatedTimeHour, y = df()$count_dir, color = df()$direction,
              # ??hcaes(x = df()$updatedTimeHour, y = df()$count_dir, color = df()$direction)
              ) %>%
              hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime',
                       # ??group = factor(df()$direction),
                       categories = df()$updatedTimeHour,
                       tickmarkPlacement = "on",
                       opposite = FALSE) %>%
              hc_title(text = "NetFlows, by Hour",
                       style = list(fontWeight = "bold")) %>% 
              hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE, filename = "threat_extract")
```

[image: No groups or colors mapped to the 4 direction levels]

As you can probably tell, I'm very confused about where/how to map the x-grouping `udpatedTimeHour`, or color the different `direction` levels appropriately and make sure their `group` ends up mapped correctly to the labels in the legend and hover.

I have also attempted to map these aesthetics using the `hcaes()` call I see included as an argument to `hc_add_series()` in some of the documentation, but I get errors thrown saying that that argument is not (any longer?) named in that `hc_` function...

Any help is appreciated, and a related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790422/how-do-i-coerce-contents-of-a-reactive-to-a-data-frame?noredirect=1#comment72695370_42790422).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add as one series multiple objects that's the reason why is not working. Just changing a little bit your code and using the "magic" function `hchart` it should work:

```
df = data_frame(updatedTimeHour = c(6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8), direction = c(1,2,0,3,2,0,1,3,1), count_dir = rnorm(9))
type = "line"
hchart(df, type, hcaes(x = updatedTimeHour, y = count_dir, group = as.factor(direction))) %>% 
   hc_title(text = "NetFlows, by Hour",
       style = list(fontWeight = "bold")) %>% 
   hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE, filename = "threat_extract")
```

[image]

Comment: You, sir, are the man.  I think a large part of my issues were with were I was dealing with the reactive that makes df, but I needed this piece, as well.