# How do I coerce contents of a reactive to a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, highcharts, shiny

I am having a lot of trouble adopting a good flow of object types as a shiny R reactive object is structured and moves data through my app. This is especially true if I am trying to `dplyr::filter()` a reactive's contents and return them to a `base::data.frame` or `DT::data.table`.

I see a lot of suggestion to "just to `df()$element` like any closure," but in a lot of cases (like Highcharter or using `%in%` to check sets) I have to store (`df <- df()`) before I can use `x %in% df`...

Say I have

```
> foo <- reactiveValues()
> str(foo)
List of 3
 $ impl    :Classes 'ReactiveValues', 'R6' <ReactiveValues>
  Public:
    .allValuesDeps: environment
    .dependents: environment
    .label: reactiveValues8306
    .metadata: environment
    .namesDeps: environment
    .setLabel: function (label) 
    .values: environment
    .valuesDeps: environment
    clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
    freeze: function (key) 
    get: function (key) 
    getMeta: function (key, metaKey) 
    initialize: function () 
    isFrozen: function (key) 
    mset: function (lst) 
    names: function () 
    self: ReactiveValues, R6
    set: function (key, value) 
    setMeta: function (key, metaKey, value) 
    thaw: function (key) 
    toList: function (all.names = FALSE)  
 $ readonly: logi FALSE
 $ ns      :function (x)  
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "reactivevalues"
```

I can store a `data.frame` in this reactive, as I do often when filtering:

```
> foo$config <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))
```

But, now I can only get myself in trouble:

```
> foo()
Error: could not find function "foo"
> foo$config
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
> foo()$config
Error: could not find function "foo"
```

Usually at this point in the shiny-app building process I resort to trying to strong-arm the object into the form I want.  Checking that object with `renderPrints` of calls to `typeof()` and `class()` usually tell me it is the object I'm looking for ("`list`", "`data.table`", or "`data.frame`") but the object will usually not conform then to the expected output of calls to `renderDataTable` or the aesthetic mappings in graphing libraries like ggplot or highcharter.

Can someone give me a better idea of what is going on?  Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789833/having-trouble-mapping-highcharter-aesthetics-to-reactive-object-elements).

Comment: You can look at `?reactiveValues`. `foo$config` works but you need to be in a reactive environment as the error states.

Comment: Understood - so when I'm in that reactive environment, how would I store its contents to a reactive-free `data.frame` or `data.table` object? (Also, I RTFM: "Note that values taken from the reactiveValues object are reactive" does not help and there is not much else).

Comment: I think that's the wrong approach.  renderDataTable is a reactive environment, so why worry about it?  If you need to do extra work on the data, just pass the reactive data set to a new object within renderDataTable({   }) and work on it there with the last call being what you want returned.  Something like:  `renderDataTable({ df <- data(); df %>% filter(); df })` but adapted, of course, to whatever you need to do on it.

Comment: But if I want to use `df` across multiple reactive environments like `renderDataTable` as well as `renderHighChart`? @RyanMorton

Comment: No, you'd use data() across multiple reactive environments.  If you need to pass df, you'd need to create that as it's own reactive value.